# Placing text in a node typeset on two lines to the right of the midpoint of an arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I place the text "Construction of edge from Vertex \textit{b}" at the midpoint of the arrow pointing downwards? As it is typeset now, it seems the top of the node is typeset at the midpoint of the arrow.

I would also like to see a similar graph with the downward arrow bowing to the left and the node to the left of the midpoint of this arrow. I know it involves the option `to[in=theta, out=\phi, looseness=a]`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize}, shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}]

%A sequence of graphs is drawn, starting with the vertex with the b-label b.


%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b.
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
%
\draw (-4,-3) -- (-2,-3);
\draw[fill] (-4,-3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-3) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){$b - 1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
%
%An arrow is drawn to the next diagram.
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b) -- (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b);
\path node[anchor=west, align=center] at ($($(label_for_Vertex_b)!0.5!(label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b)$) +(0.1,0)$)
{Construction of edge\\
from vertex \textit{b}};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional way is to just use `midway` and to put the node after the line.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize}, shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}]

%A sequence of graphs is drawn, starting with the vertex with the b-label b.


%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b.
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
%
\draw (-4,-3) -- (-2,-3);
\draw[fill] (-4,-3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-3) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){$b - 1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
%
%An arrow is drawn to the next diagram.
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b) -- (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b)
node[midway,right=1mm, align=center]{Construction of edge\\
from vertex \textit{b}};


\end{tikzpicture}
~vs.~\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize}, shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}]

%A sequence of graphs is drawn, starting with the vertex with the b-label b.


%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b.
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
%
\draw (-4,-3) -- (-2,-3);
\draw[fill] (-4,-3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-3) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){$b - 1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
%
%An arrow is drawn to the next diagram.
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b) -- (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b);
\path node[anchor=west, align=center] at ($($(label_for_Vertex_b)!0.5!(label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b)$) +(0.1,0)$)
{Construction of edge\\
from vertex \textit{b}};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The picture on the right is the original, which has small offset because the labels/nodes are extended objects, and the arrow connects their boundaries and not their centers. Note also that there is a bit of an "optical illusion" because the node is at the center of the full arrow, including its head. If you want to have the node at the center of the headless arrow, this could be done, too.

Please notice that this is the syntax that works for `--` paths. For general paths use

```
\draw[<options>] (start) to[<options>] node [midway,<options>]{<test>} (end);
```

Since `midway` is the default option, you could just use

```
\draw[<options>] (start) to[<options>] node [<options>]{<test>} (end);
```

For instance,

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize}, shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}]

%A sequence of graphs is drawn, starting with the vertex with the b-label b.


%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b.
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
%
\draw (-4,-3) -- (-2,-3);
\draw[fill] (-4,-3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-3) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){$b - 1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
%
%An arrow is drawn to the next diagram.
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] 
(label_for_Vertex_b) to[bend right=20] node[right=1mm, align=center]{Construction of edge\\
from vertex \textit{b}} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would I use `(label_for_Vertex_b.south)!0.5!(label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b.north)`?

Comment: What command would I use for the bowed arrow? I am inclined to have a bowed arrow drawn.

Comment: @user74973 Yes, you could use `label_for_Vertex_b.south)!0.5!(label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b.north)`. But this requires you to know that the path runs from north to south. `midway` doesn't require you to put this knowledge in, is also works for horizontal or diagonal or arbitrary paths without the need of changing the syntax. For bent arrows you can use `\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] 
(label_for_Vertex_b) to[bend left=20] node[midway,right=1mm, align=center]{Construction of edge\\
from vertex \textit{b}} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b)
;`, say.

Comment: The arrows in this diagram are all pointing downward.

Comment: I think that I am going to draw bowed arrows. In this case, I will use `bend right=20` so that the arrow is "outside" the graph.

Comment: Thanks for your help, again!

Comment: @user74973 You're welcome! And I agree, `bend right` looks better.

Answer (score 2):

I would draw you image on a different way. For edge labels would use `quotes` library, for vertex I would use node with circle shape and for their labels use `label` macro with names. For vertex positions I would use relative coordinates determined by `positioning` libraries:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
    node distance = 22mm and 22mm,
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\footnotesize,
                            align=center},
      every label/.style = {fill=white, inner sep= 2pt,
                            font=\footnotesize},
              dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill, minimum size=3pt,
                            inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                            node contents={}}
                    ]
\node (n1) [dot,
            label={[name=n1a]$\frac{0}{1}$},
            label={[name=n1b]below:$b$}
            ];
\node (n2) [dot, below=of n1,
            label={[name=n2a]$\frac{0}{1}$},
            label={[name=n2b]below:$b$}
            ];
\node (n3) [dot, right=of n2,
            label={[name=n3a]$\frac{1}{1}$},
            label={[name=n3b]below:$b-1$}
            ];
%
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt]
        (n1b) edge["Construction of edge\\
                    from vertex \textit{b}",
                    bend left] (n2a);
\draw   (n2) -- (n3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]